# Cannot change keyboard backlight with dbus-send

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, brightness, backlight

I have kde desktop environment, and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> / <kbd>F4</kbd> buttons cannot change keyboard brightness.

I also assign other keys to increase or decrease keyboard brightness in global shortcuts menu, but its not work again.

---

So I try to change brightness level by this command:

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

And keyboard brightness change **successfully**.

But kde uses dbus to change keyboard brightness, So I try to use this command (which can be found in [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/keyboard_backlight)):

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply=literal --system --dest='org.freedesktop.UPower' '/org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight' 'org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight.SetBrightness' int32:2
```

But brightness not changes at all and I got this error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight” on object at path /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight
```

So I try change permission of that file:

```
sudo chmod 666 /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

‌But I can't change keyboard brightness by <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> / <kbd>F4</kbd> or dbus again.

---

Additional information:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> keys combinations works well and I can see signal sends well:

```
$ xev | sed -n 's/^.*state \([0-9].*\), keycode *\([0-9]\+\) *\(.*\), .*$/keycode \2 = \3, state = \1/p'
keycode 237 = (keysym 0x1008ff06, XF86KbdBrightnessDown), state = 0x10
keycode 237 = (keysym 0x1008ff06, XF86KbdBrightnessDown), state = 0x10
keycode 238 = (keysym 0x1008ff05, XF86KbdBrightnessUp), state = 0x10
keycode 238 = (keysym 0x1008ff05, XF86KbdBrightnessUp), state = 0x10
```

---

So how can I change keyboard brightness with dbus?

Comment: What is the version of yours `upower` ?

Comment: @AliRazmdideh 0.99.8-2

Comment: What the output of this comand : `journalctl | grep -i upowerd`

Comment: @AliRazmdideh `upowerd[2907]: up_kbd_backlight_brightness_read: assertion 'fd >= 0' failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are using `0.99.8-2` version of `upower` package.

In the last update of `upower` many distribution users, like Debian unstable, Arch linux, Ubuntu cosmic, have encountered this problem.

For example [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower/issues/73) issue is related yours, has opened in `upower` GitLab page.

According to that link, this method should be solve your problem (which has solved my problem on debian sid):

1.Make override configuration for `upower` service:

```
sudo systemctl edit upower.service
```

2.Write these lines in it:

```
[Service]
ProtectKernelTunables=false
```

3.Check the changes by this command:

```
systemctl show upower.service | grep ProtectKernelTunables
```

If you see this output, you did it right:

```
ProtectKernelTunables=no
```

For more details about `ProtectKernelTunables=` parameter, you can see [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).

4.Reboot your system (also you can restart `upower` and `dbus` services but its better reboot system to restart all services completely).

5.Check your keyboard backlight. Now you should not see somethigs like this, in the output of `journalctl | grep -i upowerd` command:

```
upowerd[2907]: up_kbd_backlight_brightness_read: assertion 'fd >= 0' failed
```

And your keyboard backlight should be change with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> key combinations or dbus command:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply=literal --system --dest='org.freedesktop.UPower' '/org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight' 'org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight.SetBrightness' int32:3
```